# How to check node process thread count

Tags: node.js

I'd like to get the node process's thread count or threads, something like `process.threads.length` is how I would describe it. On macOS, I can easily see node's threads by going to Activity Monitor > CPU > search for "node", and it says 12 threads. How can I do this in simple Node.JS code **without** any external libraries? Also looking for the process memory as well because Activity monitor says Node is taking up 16mb in total, while my code says 11mb memory in total.

Only thing i found is how to CREATE worker processes and threads.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can read it from `/proc/$pid/status`

Here's a synchronous one liner

```
> require("fs").readFileSync(`/proc/${process.pid}/status`).toString().match(/Threads\W+([0-9]+)/)?.[1]
'12'
```